# JQuery Moving 30 boxes from left to right, then right to right

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm learning Jquery right now and I'm stuck on how I move my boxes from left to right, then right to left. They have a delay meter that I can use as well to change the speed. I just don't know what I'm missing to make the boxes move in the two specified directions (Left To Right, Right To Left). I'm assuming it's something simple, that's usually the case. But, I'm not sure what to change. Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
var easingsList = [
"swing",
"easeInQuad",
"easeOutQuad",
"easeInOutQuad",
"easeInCubic",
"easeOutCubic",
"easeInOutCubic",
"easeInQuart",
"easeOutQuart",
"easeInOutQuart",
"easeInQuint",
"easeOutQuint",
"easeInOutQuint",
"easeInSine",
"easeOutSine",
"easeInOutSine",
"easeInExpo",
"easeOutExpo",
"easeInOutExpo",
"easeInCirc",
"easeOutCirc",
"easeInOutCirc",
"easeInElastic",
"easeOutElastic",
"easeInOutElastic",
"easeInBack",
"easeOutBack",
"easeInOutBack",
"easeInBounce",
"easeOutBounce"
];

    var moveRight = function(){
      var n = 0;
      var e = easingsList[n];
      var d = parseInt($("#delay").val());
      moveBoxRight(n, e, d);

      var n = 1;
      var e = easingsList[n];
      var d = parseInt($("#delay").val());
      moveBoxRight(n, e, d);



    }

    var moveLeft = function(){
    var n = 0;
    var e = easingsList[n];
    var d = parseInt($)"#delay").val());
    moveBoxLeft (n, e, d);

    var n = 1;
      var e = easingsList[n];
      var d = parseInt($("#delay").val());
      moveBoxLeft(n, e, d);
    }

    var moveBoxRight= function(n, easing, duration)
    {
      var id = "#button" + n.toString();
      var pageWidth = $("body").width();
      var boxWidth = 150;
      $(id).animate({"margin-left":pageWidth-boxWidth + "px"}, duration, easing); 
    }

    var moveBoxLeft= function(n, easing, duration)
    {
      var id = "#button" + n.toString();
      var pageWidth = $("body").width();
      var boxWidth = 150;
      $(id).animate({"margin-left" : "0px"}, duration, easing); 
    }

    *******and heres my HTML*********

    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title> jQuery animate()</title>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.3.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script src="jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script src="test.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <style>
      body
      {
        margin: 0;
      }
      .button{
       height:50px;
       width:150px;
       display: block;
       border: solid 1px black; 
       text-align: center;
       text-decoration: none;
       margin-bottom: 10px;
       line-height: 50px;
      }
    </style>
    </head>


    <body>
      <h1> jQuery Animate Easing Examples </h1>

      <input placeholder='delay; 100ms, 1s etc.'  id='delay'>
      <input placeholder='end color; rgb(0,0,0), #000000, rgba(0,0,0,1)  etc.'  id='endColor'>
      <br>
      <a href='javascript:moveLeft()' class='link'  id='button1'> Move Left </a>
      <a href='javascript:moveRight()' class='link' style='float:right'  id='button1'> Move Right </a>

      <div class='button' id='button0'> swing </div>
      <div class='button' id='button1'>easeInQuad</div>
      <div class='button' id='button2'>easOutQuad</div>
      <div class='button' id='button3'>easeInOutQuad</div>
      <div class='button' id='button4'>easeInCubic</div>
      <div class='button' id='button5'>easeOutCubic</div>
      <div class='button' id='button6'>easeInOutCubic</div>
      <div class='button' id='button7'>easeInQuart</div>
      <div class='button' id='button8'>easeOutQuart</div>
      <div class='button' id='button9'>easeInOutQuart</div>
      <div class='button' id='button10'>easInQuint</div>
      <div class='button' id='button11'>easeOutQuint</div>
      <div class='button' id='button12'>easeInOutQuint</div>
      <div class='button' id='button13'>easeInSine</div>
      <div class='button' id='button14'>easeOutSine</div>
      <div class='button' id='button15'>easeInOutSine</div>
      <div class='button' id='button16'>easeInExpo</div>
      <div class='button' id='button17'>easeOutExpo</div>
      <div class='button' id='button18'>easeInOutExpo</div>
      <div class='button' id='button19'>easeInCirc</div>
      <div class='button' id='button20'>easeOutCirc</div>
      <div class='button' id='buton21'>easeInOutCirc</div>
      <div class='button' id='button22'>easeInElasic</div>
      <div class='button' id='button23'>easeOutElastic</div>
      <div class='button' id='button24'>easeInOutElatic</div>
      <div class='button' id='button25'>easeInBack</div>
      <div class='button' id='button26'>easeOutBack</div>
      <div class='button' id='button27'>easeInOutBack</div>
      <div class='button' id='button28'>easeInBounce</div>
      <div class='button' id='button29'>easeOutBounce</div>



      </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You have mistake in `moveLeft` method

`var d = parseInt($)"#delay").val());`

Comment: Whats the mistake? and how do I fix it?

Comment: var d = parseInt($("#delay").val())

Comment: Are there any other mistakes, because it's still not moving.

Comment: *"Are there any other mistakes"* ... check your browser console for errors. Console is your first line of troubleshooting...get familiar with it's capabilities. Most errors you see can be thrown into google search if you don't understand them

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, your approach can be improved altogether

- Firstly, animating the margin property of an element is not a good way to move it left and right. Making the element fixed and animating the `left` and `right` properties would work much better.
- Secondly, you could greatly simplify the code by using an attribute on the button to determine direction instead of writing duplicated code with just a few words different for moving left vs right.
- Also, your calling your variable `delay` but using that variable to set the animation's `duration` which is misleading. You should re-name that `duration`

Here's how I would do it:

```js
var easingsList = [
  "swing",
  "easeInQuad",
  "easeOutQuad",
  "easeInOutQuad",
  "easeInCubic",
  "easeOutCubic",
  "easeInOutCubic",
  "easeInQuart",
  "easeOutQuart",
  "easeInOutQuart",
  "easeInQuint",
  "easeOutQuint",
  "easeInOutQuint",
  "easeInSine",
  "easeOutSine",
  "easeInOutSine",
  "easeInExpo",
  "easeOutExpo",
  "easeInOutExpo",
  "easeInCirc",
  "easeOutCirc",
  "easeInOutCirc",
  "easeInElastic",
  "easeOutElastic",
  "easeInOutElastic",
  "easeInBack",
  "easeOutBack",
  "easeInOutBack",
  "easeInBounce",
  "easeOutBounce"
];


$('.move').click(function(){
  var $this=$(this); 
  var duration = parseInt($("#duration").val());
  var direction = $(this).data('direction');
  var n =0;
  moveBox($('.box').eq(n), easingsList[n], duration, direction);
  moveBox($('.box').eq(n+1), easingsList[n+1], duration, direction);
  
});

function moveBox($element, easing, duration, direction) {
  var pageWidth = $("body").width();
  var boxWidth = $element.width();
  $element.css('right','auto').css('left','auto');
  var options = {duration:duration,easing:easing};
  var properties ={};
  properties[direction]=pageWidth - boxWidth + "px";
  $element.stop().animate(properties,options);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  display: block;
  border: solid 1px black;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  line-height: 50px;
  position:fixed;
}
.box-holder{
  width: 100%;
  position:relative;
   height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<h1> jQuery Animate Easing Examples </h1>

<input placeholder='duration; 100ms, 1s etc.' id='duration' value="3000">
<input placeholder='end color; rgb(0,0,0), #000000, rgba(0,0,0,1)  etc.' id='endColor'>
<br>
<a href='#' class='link move' data-direction="right" > Move Left </a>
<a href='#' class='link move' data-direction="left" style='float:right'> Move Right </a>
<div class="box-holder"><div class="box"> swing </div> </div>
<div class="box-holder"><div class="box">easeInQuad</div></div>
<div class="box-holder"><div class="box">easOutQuad</div></div>
<div class="box-holder"><div class="box">easeInOutQuad</div></div>
<div class="box-holder"><div class="box">easeInCubic</div></div>
<div class="box-holder"><div class="box">easeOutCubic</div></div>
<div class="box-holder"><div class="box">easeInOutCubic</div></div>
<div class="box-holder"><div class="box">easeInQuart</div></div>
<div class="box-holder"><div class="box">easeOutQuart</div></div>
<div class="box-holder"><div class="box">easeInOutQuart</div></div>
<div class="box-holder"><div class="box">easInQuint</div></div>
<div class="box-holder"><div class="box">easeOutQuint</div></div>
<div class="box-holder"><div class="box">easeInOutQuint</div></div>
<div class="box-holder"><div class="box">easeInSine</div></div>
<div class="box-holder"><div class="box">easeOutSine</div></div>
<div class="box-holder"><div class="box">easeInOutSine</div></div>
<div class="box-holder"><div class="box">easeInExpo</div></div>
<div class="box-holder"><div class="box">easeOutExpo</div></div>
<div class="box-holder"><div class="box">easeInOutExpo</div></div>
<div class="box-holder"><div class="box">easeInCirc</div></div>
<div class="box-holder"><div class="box">easeOutCirc</div></div>
<div class="box-holder"><div class="box">easeInOutCirc</div></div>
<div class="box-holder"><div class="box">easeInElasic</div></div>
<div class="box-holder"><div class="box">easeOutElastic</div></div>
<div class="box-holder"><div class="box">easeInOutElatic</div></div>
<div class="box-holder"><div class="box">easeInBack</div></div>
<div class="box-holder"><div class="box">easeOutBack</div></div>
<div class="box-holder"><div class="box">easeInOutBack</div></div>
<div class="box-holder"><div class="box">easeInBounce</div></div>
<div class="box-holder"><div class="box">easeOutBounce</div></div>
```